# Redirect user to custom url based on the username after Login Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Hello? I am trying to redirect a particular user to a custom page once they log in in django. The Admin will be directed to their usual admin interface while this particular user will go to their own custom page.
I have written this code and placed it in my views

```
def custLogin(request):
    if request.user.username == '***':
        return HttpResponseRedirect('http://********************.html')
    else:
        return login(request,template_name='login.html')
```

I have pointed the accounts/login url in urls.py to custLogin as below

```
(r'^accounts/login/', custLogin),
```

I however keep getting the error

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Any pointers please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you should use [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut, which returns an `HttpResponseRedirect`, to point your users to different places after `custLogin` view processed.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
def custLogin(request):
    if request.user.is_staff:
        return redirect('/some/admin/url')
    else:
        return redirect('/some/regular/user/url')
```

As documentation says, you can use the `redirect()` function in a number of ways: by passing a view name, an object or url. See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) for more info

Note, that I use [`is_staff`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff) user field to determine: is user an admin or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your template, you may have forgotten to do this at the beginning of your template:

```
{% load from future url %}
```

This is useful when using:

```
{% url 'name_of_my_url_inurl.py' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

For redirecting each user to his own page use `reverse`

First create url route which accepts parameter. It's described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)

And redirect like

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('arch-summary', args=[1945]))
```

where *arch-summary* - named url, and in list *args* - parameters for it. Example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse)

To distinguish admin user from usual user, check it in view and redirect to different url.